# Accessing threads outside main()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a `Player.java` class and a `Driver.java` class. I need to set up communication between threads. I have them set up in an array and I am able to access the attributes from each in my main(). However, I need to use synchronization with my program and am not sure how to access my threads (created in `Driver`) in my `Player` class.

How can I access these threads outside of the `main()` method in order to manipulate them in my `run()` method?

Comment: I would start with a quick [Google on "java thread communication"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java%20thread%20communication&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp).  Basically, each thread will need some reference to a common point or model through which they can communicate.  Depending on the importance of the communication, you could use thread synchronization to wait for some state in the model to occur before the thread carries on, common known as the producer-consumer pattern

Comment: Can you post some code snippets here? That will help to understand your requirement well.

Comment: So, your question is "how can threads communicate with each other"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java 7, take a look at [TransferQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TransferQueue.html).

Answer (score 0):

for threads communication, you need to create some shared data, and synchronize them. then use wait/notify mechanism to interact between threads.